# What percent of heap memory is accessed between consecutive GCs (in HotSpot)?

Tags: java

What percent of heap memory is accessed between consecutive GCs (in HotSpot)?
The question is to determine what percent of objects (or heap space) is
accessed by the program in a specific time interval (few seconds) or between consecutive GC
invocations.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? How would you use this information?

Comment: All dynamically allocated objects in a Java program are allocated space on the heap. Over time, old
objects die, and new objects are created. A JVM uses garbage collection (GC) to remove dead objects
from the heap. From the set of live objects, it is possible that the program only uses a small set of
objects at any one time. The project is to determine what percent of objects (or heap space) is
accessed by the program in a specific time interval (few seconds) or between consecutive GC
invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using jmap (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) which is part of the JDK and/or jstat (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html) on a java program with one or more long-running loops that allocate and free objects.